# Полетели шрифты в консоли

Tags: linux, ubuntu, шрифты, консоль, elementary-os

В консоли линукса (elementary) полетели шрифты, во всех остальных приложениях шрифты нормальные, устанавливал всё для msf и VirualBox, вот скрин:

[image: Консоль1]]

Comment: зайдите в настройки терминала и выставьте подходящие красивые шрифты

Comment: Я так и делал, ubuntu Regular

Comment: Попробуйте другие шрифты

Comment: В консоли от pantheon нету настроек

Comment: очень странная "убунта":) https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-change-the-default-terminal-font

Comment: Это оболочка pantheon, Vlad Spirin тег добавил зачем-то

Comment: Поменял на Elementary OS, сорри прозевал

Comment: Никто, не добавляйте и не удаляйте теги, в вопросе есть linux, шрифты консоль, стоит убунту, соответственно консоль не арча, не других дистрибутивов, а оболочка pantheon - elementary-os

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как по Elementary OS пока не так много ответов в русскоязычном StackOverflow, переведу ответ с англоязычного ресурса, ссылку в комментариях на который предоставил KoVadim.

---

Чтобы изменить шрифт в терминале, вам нужен `dconf-editor`.
Установите его, если вы еще этого не сделали:

```
sudo apt install dconf-tools
```

Запустите его и следуйте по пути:

```
org > gnome > desktop > interface > monospace-font-name
```

Введите название нужного шрифта и размер шрифта. Например: `Anonymous Pro 11`.
Вы также можете использовать команду:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings font 'Anonymous Pro 11'
```

в терминале, вместо `dconf-editor`.

Comment: Еще можно установить твики и в параметре шрифты>моноширный шрифт, и любой шрифт, мне помогло.